# How do I "capture" a string variable in an expression tree, instead of having a constant?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression-trees

I'm using this method to dynamically construct an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` for use in an `IQueryable.Where()`

```
private Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> EqualToExpression<TSource, TValue>(
    Expression<Func<TSource, TValue>> selectValue, 
    TValue targetValue)
{
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(
            selectValue.Body,
            Expression.Constant(targetValue)),
        selectValue.Parameters);
}
```

I use it like this (simplified example):

```
var query = this.Context.Set<Car>();
string makeFilter = "BMW";
Expression<Func<Car, string>> makeProperty = (x) => x.Make;

query = query.Where(EqualToExpression(makeProperty , makeFilter));
```

The query is then executed by EF Core, and it works.

The problem is that EF Core treats `targetValue` as a constant, and hard codes the value into the SQL, instead of lifting it out as a parameter to the query.

Can I change my `EqualToExpression` method so that `targetValue` is "captured" as a parameter?

Comment: This question does indeed appear to be a duplicate of the linked question. (This stuff is hard to search for!) I've got it working use the answer from the other question.